# What is the proper way to pass a variable when page refresh/reload using php?

Tags: php, html, variables, state, global

I've a php page that refreshes every minute and on it an php array global variable that I use to compare values (before and after a page refresh).

But I've a problem, whenever the page is refreshed, the php array is resetted. I know that's because HTML is stateless but I want to mantain the state of this array.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for sessions
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['arr']['counter'])) {
 $SESSION['arr']['counter'] = 0;
} else {
 $SESSION['arr']['counter']++;
}
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

Comment: Can I set a `$SESSION variable` after `<html>` tag? I know that's not possible with cookies.

Comment: I've just tested and it works, thanks for the quick answer, I'll accept it in one minute :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php), [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php), [database](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20database), [memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php), [redis](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20redis), files, ... take your pick.